# About to run Agentsims in Google colab environment ( tuneling by ngrok and ...)

Tags: google-colaboratory

So I need to run the Agentsims into google colab and I can not see its http://localhost:8000/index.html page in curl or tuneling.

I have past the code at the below colab page for your test in this [available link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Efm4YoF5W5wcaVbW7kEwBJzBQI4bBNT5#scrollTo=EhpXJ63mC9a9) :

![enter image description here]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9kRg.jpg)

So I asked at the main Agentsims github page too at [this link](https://github.com/py499372727/AgentSims/issues/13)

.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.